# Customizing x-axis tick labels on PF's bar chart

Tags: primefaces, bar-chart

I'm trying to display a list ob objects on a PF's bar chart. Let's say that object MyObject has three attributes: attr1, attr2 and attr3. I would like to display attribute attr1 on x-axis and attr2 on y-axis. I already managed to do that, but there's another problem. I would also like to open a dialog with some additional info about a particular object wheh user clicks on a bar. For that dialog to be loaded, I need attr3 of MyObject object, but there are only attr1 and attr2 stored in a model.

I'm creating chart series of a model like this:

```
for (MyObject obj : objList){
    ser1.set(obj.getAttr1(), obj.getAttr2());
}
```

If I store the whole object in a series, like this:

```
for (MyObject obj : objList){
       ser1.set(obj, obj.getAttr2());
}
```

I get attr3 value, when I click on a bar, but there's also the whole object displayed as label on a x-axis. So, is there any way to customize that label to display just attr1 in a chart and store the whole object in a model at the same time? Or maybe some other way to store the whole object in a model and display just some attributes?

Thanks in advance!

PS: Using Primefaces 5.3.

Comment: please improve your question... to much mixed and unrelated information.

Comment: What information in my question is not related to my problem? I just described what I'm trying to achieve and what I did so far...